# Phonegap-Angular-HammerJs hybrid web application: Get X/Y for a hm-tap event

Tags: angularjs, hammer.js, hybrid-mobile-app

In our Phonegap-Angular-HammerJs hybrid web application, I am trying to get the X and Y coordinates for a hm-tap event. But I found hm-tap event does not have the clientX and clientY attributes like an ng-click event.

How can we find the X/Y coordinates for a hm-tap/hmTap event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access

```
ev.gesture.touches[0].pageX;
```